# python kernel connection with vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an ubuntu machine.
And I download jupyter and python extensions in VScode.
But when I want to run any code in the jupyter notebook. It doesn't run and I can't open the .ipynb files. VScode shows the following error:

[image: error]

[image: vscode]

PS: I haven't installed anaconda because I want to use the python kernel installed previously and not use the python kernel of anaconda.

Comment: It is not what you asked but you should use Python3.x. Python 2.7 is no longer supported. It could solve your problem in the same time.

Comment: Do you have Jupyter installed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some issues with Jupyter Extension. Could you try these?

1. Install another version of Jupyter NoteBook, Downgrade or Upgrade it and then restart it.
2. Avoid running the VSCode as admin.

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122951) page and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128649) page for more details